# Rewriting image URLs in nginx from a shortened URL to a specific directory

Tags: images, nginx

I'm using an image serving application on nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu), but it was made for Apache2. Images are uploaded to directory "/imageshare/images/extension/" where the filename is randomly generated, but the URL outputted by the application is  shortened, located at domain.tld/image/filename.

The application maintainer gives advice on .htaccess for Apache2, but says they can't provide help for Nginx. What can I put in my Nginx configuration file to redirect images to a different URL on the same domain while not changing the location of those files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To direct the URL `domain.tld/image/filename` to the local path `/imageshare/images/extension/filename`, use the `alias` directive (see [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details):

```
location /image/ {
    alias /path/to/imageshare/images/extension/;
}
```

If you really do mean to *rewrite* the URL to another URL, use:

```
location /image/ {
    rewrite ^/image(.*)$ /imageshare/images/extension$1 last;
}
```

See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details. The `last` modifier causes the rewrite to be *internal*, which means that the client does not see it. Use `redirect` or `permanent` to make the redirection visible to the client.